# How can I copy all my disorganized files into a single directory? (on linux)

Tags: bash, shell

I have thousands of mp3s inside a complex folder structure which resides within a single folder. I would like to move all the mp3s into a single directory with no subfolders.  I can think of a variety of ways of doing this using the `find` command but one problem will be duplicate file names. I don't want to replace files since I often have multiple versions of a same song. Auto-rename would be best. I don't really care how the files are renamed.

Does anyone know a simple and safe way of doing this?

Comment: How is this not programming related?

Comment: I agree that this is programming related, but the question makes that decidedly non-obvious.  You're essentially asking how to write a program that solves his problem.  Maybe you should edit the question to emphasize that aspect and you'll get it reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change a `a/b/c.mp3` path into `a - b - c.mp3` after copying.  Here's a solution in Bash:

```
find srcdir -name '*.mp3' -printf '%P\n' |
    while read i; do
        j="${i//\// - }"
        cp -v "srcdir/$i" "dstdir/$j"
    done
```

And in a shell without `${//}` substitution:

```
find srcdir -name '*.mp3' -printf '%P\n' |
    sed -e 'p;s:/: - :g' |
    while read i; do
        read j
        cp -v "srcdir/$i" "dstdir/$j"
    done
```

For a different scheme, GNU's `cp` and `mv` can make numbered backups instead of overwriting -- see `-b`/`--backup[=CONTROL]` in the man pages.

```
find srcdir -name '*.mp3' -exec cp -v --backup=numbered {} dstdir/ \;
```

Answer (score 2):

bash like pseudocode:

```
for i in `find . -name "*.mp3"`; do
    NEW_NAME = `basename $i`
    X=0
    while ! -f move_to_dir/$NEW_NAME
        NEW_NAME = $NEW_NAME + incr $X

    mv $i $NEW_NAME
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
NEW_DIR=/tmp/new/

IFS="
"; for a in `find . -type f `
    do
    echo "$a"
    new_name="`basename $a`"
    while test -e "$NEW_DIR/$new_name"
            do
            new_name="${new_name}_"
            done
    cp "$a" "$NEW_DIR/$new_name"
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend to do this in a simple script rather than try to fit in in a single command line.

For instance, in python, it would be relatively trivial to do a walk() through the directory, copying each mp3 file found to a different directory with an automatically incremented number.

If you want to get fancier, you could have a dictionary of existing file names, and simply append a number to the duplicates. (the index of the dictionary being the file name, and the value being the number of files found so far, which would become your suffix)

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/mp3s -name *.mp3 -exec mv \{\} /path/to/target/dir \;
```

Comment: this won't deal with the duplicate filenames issue mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of many downvotes, a perl script could be written in short time to accomplish this.

Pseudocode:

```
while (-e filename)
     change filename to filename . "1";
```

Answer (score 1):

In python: to actually move the file, change debug=False

```
import os, re
from_dir="/from/dir"
to_dir = "/target/dir"
re_ext = "\.mp3"
debug = True

w = os.walk(from_dir)
n = w.next()
while n:
    d, arg, names = n
    names = filter(lambda fn: re.match(".*(%s)$"%re_ext, fn, re.I) , names)
    n = w.next()
    for fn in names:
        from_fn     = os.path.join(d,fn)
        target_fn   = os.path.join(to_dir, fn)
        file_exists = os.path.exists(target_fn)
        if not debug:
            if not file_exists:
                os.rename(from_fn, target_fn)
            else:
                print "DO NOT MOVE - FILE EXISTS ", from_fn
        else:
            print "MOVE ", from_fn, " TO " , target_fn
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care how the duplicate files are named, utilize the 'backup' option on move:

```
find /path/to/mp3s -name *.mp3 -exec mv --backup=numbered {} /path/to/target/dir \;
```

Will get you:

- song.mp3
- song.mp3.~1~
- song.mp3.~2~